# Creating a form with GET bypases the validation and submit

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating a simple form, when sumits, shows result from an external API.
But URL remain the same, so you cant get a url if your search result and send it to someone.

But when I use get

```
$form['method'] = 'get';
```

It shows a construted url..

```
mysite.com/search?cat=2$coutry=3
```

But it donot fetch the result, cause it is bypassing the submit and validation functions. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the page or form check for the presence of your variables, using `drupal_get_query_parameters()`, and if present, perform validation checks and get results from the external API, and display.

For example,

```
$params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if ( isset($params['cat']) ) {
  //validate $params['cat']
    if ( myValidationCheck($params['cat']) ) {
      $results = myExternalAPIGetResults($params['cat']);
      $form['results'] = myResultsDisplay($results);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is somwhow working for me. But two issues, 1. I cant figure if form is submitted or not, like  -if (!empty($form_state['submitted']))- 2. After submit click, form field value cahnged to default, not the one I selected to see result. e-g If I select, CAT01 from Category, and default is CAT, it changes back to CAT.

Comment: Also it works for me only if I use it inside where I am creating form, cz no validate or submit works, but that's fine for me. :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, Ignore point 1 but point 2. When I submit CAT1 from dropdown(SelectField) with default 'CAT', It changes back to CAT. It shuold remain CAT1 as it is showing the result of.

Comment: Actuly I am done with this too.. '#default_value' => $params['cat']. :)